# How to discard everything in git

Tags: git

completely noob question as I try to work with git. I tried to create a new repository and I think I was simply following along these lines:

```
echo "# verstka" >> README.md  
git init  
git add README.md  
git commit -m "first commit"
```

And then something happened. When I press git status, I get lots of warnings. Here is a part of the message:

```
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied  
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied  
On branch master  
Untracked files:  
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  
.FBReader/  
.bash_history  
.gitconfig  
.instagiffer/  
.mySimula/  
.ssh/
```

And there are even more files there. In the end there is "nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)".
Can someone be kind enough and tell me what to do next, as I clearly didn't have to stage or commit all these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first initialized a git directory you would have ran

```
git init
```

This creates a folder

```
.git
```

To removal all git information simply delete the directory

```
rm -rf .git/
```

**Warning**: you'll loose all git history!

Looks like you ran git init in your home directory. Next time create a new folder first:

```
mkdir project1
cd project1
git init
...
```

Comment: You are the star, just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have accidentally created `.git` folder in your `$HOME` directory (or upper relative to your working directory), and you are seeing the warning from that. Simply, remove `.git` in your `$HOME`, it won't destroy any real files unless your `$HOME/.git` is intentional...

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what happened!